# Write a package downloader script in Python

Tags: python, pip

I want to write a script in Python that only downloads a certain package with its dependencies and doesn't install it. I want this script to be reusable, so pip is not an option as I also want it in Python code. Is there a Python package to do that?

Comment: `pip` is not reusable?

Comment: Well, can I save the scripts and use it again? Since it is run in command line, I am not sure whether someone else can just download that script and run it...

Comment: Maybe [pipenv](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv) is what you are looking for.

Comment: `pip` is included in Python since Python 2.7.9, and if you aren't at least using that, you should really upgrade because [that clock is counting down](https://pythonclock.org/). And, yes, given a list of dependencies in a text file, then `pip install -r requirements.txt` will work.

Comment: I am aware of that, but I always get syntax error when I use the commands recommended in the pip tutorials... How do I translate this into Python syntax: pip download [options] <requirement specifier> [package-index-options] ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments suggest, there is probably a better way to solve your actual problem. But for reference, there is a way to invoke pip from Python code:

```
import pip
pip.main(['download', 'pillow'])  # for example
```

This isn't a documented API, but it looks simple enough that it probably won't change in the near future.

Comment: That's, what I was looking for :) You think it also considers the dependencies? Or do I need to add something like dependencies= TRUE?

Comment: It does exactly the same as `pip download pillow` does. You can add flags to your delight.

Comment: Ok, I was able to set download directory etc. seems like it is not that difficult to translate the commands into code :) thank you once again. this was the exact thing I was looking for